# How to download files from remote windows share in jenkins?

Tags: windows, jenkins, plugins, share

I am using Publish Over CIFS plugin in Jenkins to transfer the files over to remote windows share folder.

But, it seems like there is no option available in this plugin to download files from remote windows share to local.

1. Is there any jenkins plugin can achieve this?
2. Is the the "File Operations Plugin"'s fileDownloadOperation support downloading from a windows share folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [File Operations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/File+Operations+Plugin) does work with network shares. Just use the fileCopyOperation and give the path to your share like this: `\\ShareServer\ShareName\path\to\your\file`

Comment: Hi there! How this File Operations Plugin works? When i put \\ShareServer\ShareName\path\to\your\file in "Include File Pattern" i get an error:File Copy Operation:
FATAL: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '\\ShareServer\ShareName\path\to\your\file'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax

Comment: I get the same error. There is nothing to suggest that the File Operations Plugin works with network shares, neither in its documentation nor its source code. If anything it would be the fileDownloadOperation (not the fileCopyOperation), but looking at the code, only HTTP is supported and not SMB which is what Windows file sharing typically uses.